# NodeJS multiple instances and require routes in subfolder

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm writing a multi instance NodeJS application serving my Chrome extensions.

I think I got stuck in all that is related to subfolders, requiring and exporting modules.

Here's my app structure:

[image]

At the very bottom, I have start.js which bootstraps some major parts of the application like Express, models, views, controllers, routes, etc..

```
var express = require('express'),
http = require('http'),
arguments = process.argv.slice(2),
port = arguments[0] || 3000;

var app = express(),
server = app.listen(port),
io = require('socket.io' ).listen(server ),
routes = require('./config/routes')(app);

app.configure(function(){
"use strict";

app.set('views', __dirname + '/app/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/app/public'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
});

app.configure('development', function() {
"use strict";

app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

console.log('Server is running on port ' + port);

module.exports = app;
```

In root folder of app, I have the instance files themselves. Like app.js (main), dealer.js (dealer instance), etc...

I run them like this:

> [deb0rian@localhost www.bkbot.org]$ node ./app/dealer.js 3003

app/dealer.js itself for now is pretty simple:

```
var app = require('../start.js');
app.get('/', app.routes.dealer.index);
```

And my config/routes/index.js is:

```
var fs = require('fs' ),
required_files = [];

module.exports = function(app){
fs.readdirSync(__dirname).forEach(function(file) {
    if (file == "index.js") return;
    var name = file.substr(0, file.indexOf('.'));
    require('./' + name)(app);
});
}
```

And it fails to read my route files with this error:

> [deb0rian@localhost www.bkbot.org]$ node ./app/dealer.js 3003
>
> info  - socket.io started
>
> path.js:299
>
> return splitPathRe.exec(filename).slice(1);
>                          ^
>
> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Is there something wrong with my file structure?
I want to be able to read only routes in /config/routers/dealer if I run that particular instance, no problem giving it command line argument, but i have to overcome this issue first and I don't know how to read only specific routes subdirectory.

Any help or advise will be appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: I don't think that `file` will ever be equal to `"index.js"` since it will include the full path -- but maybe I am wrong about that.  Anyway I'm pretty sure that's the issue.

Comment: file returns current file name only. I think it fails on "dealers" folder name, since it's not a file. I tried checking it: fs.lstatSync(routes_path+file).isDirectory() with this, but it says: Error: Cannot find module './dealer' which basically means my isDirectory check didn't work